# Project only keys of nested map in dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Is it possible to retrive only keys(food1, food2,.. foodN) of a nested map in dynamodb?

```
user:{
 food:{
  food1:{ value1:"",value2;""},
  food2:{ value33:""},
  ...
  foodN:{}
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not currently possible. Please refer to the [Projection Expressions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ProjectionExpressions.html) doc for more information.